# EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:data not multiple of block length for AES-256-CBC on a 16-byte ciphertext

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, aes, php-openssl

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$e = 'eyJpdiI6IkpVS2E3c1gxOGp0N3ZudERxb0hFemc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiM3MrNjkrWlNjb3lRYitxMGVPVVRPUT09IiwibWFjIjoiYTZhOWRjZjM2YTlkODc3ZDRjYjU5ODAxMmE3MGI3ZDE1ZDY5NjQzM2FmNjBkNDY5MDM1Mzg5ZTlkNDVjYjBiZSJ9';

$key = str_repeat('a', 32);

$payload = (array) json_decode(base64_decode($e));
$payload = array_map('base64_decode', $payload);

$p = openssl_decrypt(
    $payload['value'],
    'AES-256-CBC',
    $key,
    OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING,
    $payload['iv']
);

echo openssl_error_string() . "\n";

var_dump($p);
```

`$payload['value']` is 16 bytes long as is `$payload['iv']`. The block size of AES is also 16 bytes so I don't understand why I'm getting a "*data not multiple of block length*" error...

Comment: `openssl_decrypt()` base64 decodes the data by default, so you have to set the `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` flag in `$options`.

Comment: @t.m.adam - that fixed it - thanks!